# About Source Code: org.bson.Document cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a question.I use Version 2.x, look the source code.the MappingMongoConverter.class :

```
@Nullable
private <S> S read(TypeInformation<S> type, @Nullable Bson bson, ObjectPath path) {
    if (null == bson) {
        return null;
    } else {
        TypeInformation<? extends S> typeToUse = this.typeMapper.readType(bson, type);
        Class<? extends S> rawType = typeToUse.getType();
        if (this.conversions.hasCustomReadTarget(bson.getClass(), rawType)) {
            return this.conversionService.convert(bson, rawType);
        } else if (DBObject.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType)) {
            return bson;
        } else if (Document.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType)) {
            return bson;
        } else if (typeToUse.isCollectionLike() && bson instanceof List) {
            return this.readCollectionOrArray(typeToUse, (List)bson, path);
        } else if (typeToUse.isMap()) {
            return this.readMap(typeToUse, bson, path);
        } else if (bson instanceof Collection) {
            throw new MappingException(String.format("Cannot convert %1$s of type %2$s into an instance of %3$s! Implement a custom Converter<%2$s, %3$s> and register it with the CustomConversions. Parent object was: %4$s", bson, BasicDBList.class, typeToUse.getType(), path));
        } else if (typeToUse.equals(ClassTypeInformation.OBJECT)) {
            return bson;
        } else {
            Document target = bson instanceof BasicDBObject ? new Document((BasicDBObject)bson) : (Document)bson;
            MongoPersistentEntity<?> entity = (MongoPersistentEntity)this.mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(typeToUse);
            if (entity == null) {
                throw new MappingException(String.format("Expected to read Document %s into type %s but didn't find a PersistentEntity for the latter!", target, typeToUse.getType()));
            } else {
                return this.read((MongoPersistentEntity)this.mappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(typeToUse), target, path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this line:

```
else if (DBObject.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType)) {
            return bson;
        }
```

when i try to converter the response to DBObject,this is return bson.class(Document.class),For exanple:

```
List<DBObject> userList = mongoTemplate.findAll(DBObject.class, "user_info");
```

the "userList" element is Document.class  Actually。 so,when execute this code:

```
DBObject obj = userList.get(1)
```

this is a problem: "org.bson.Document cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject."

is it right? why i execute: mongoTemplate.findAll(DBObject.class, "user_info") ,i will take the Document.class of List? not DBObject.class of List?

Comment: The Version1.x,the mothod is "private <S> S read(TypeInformation<S> type, DBObject dbo, ObjectPath path)",It will be Ok. The Version2.x, the parameter DBObject dbo is replace by Bson bson. so the problem happend.